# Is DateTime.Now always monotonous when called in different processes at different times?

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say I perform `DateTime.UtcNow` in one process and some time later I do `DateTime.UtcNow` in another process (even another *exe* file).

Am I guaranteed that the first call will return a `DateTime` value that is "smaller" or equal to the second one, that is it will never happen that the first one is "larger" than second one, even if the calls are made almost at the same time (i.e. the difference between calls is 1ms or even less)?

Let's say the machine time is never changed in between those calls in any way (e.g. Windows Time service is disabled).

Comment: Unless you happen to change the DateTime of the machine in that few milSec it wont be greater i guess

Comment: Aside from anything else, `DateTime.Now` returns the *local* time, which in many time zones goes back by an hour once per year due to daylight savings. Did you actually mean to ask about `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: Yes, we can talk about `DateTime.UtcNow` to simplify things.

Comment: I suggest you update your question then. Another important aspect is what is keeping the system clock in sync - are you assuming just the Windows time service?

Comment: Updated. Let's say Windows Time service is disabled and time is never changed in between the calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes and no

Functions like `DateTime.Now` rely on timers and clocks provided by the hardware and exposed via the operating system.  The reliability of these timers and clocks is completely dependent on the platform.  That being said, I have never heard of an instance where a clock seemed to move backwards as you are describing.

### Better clocks may be available

If you are in dire need of a highly reliable, high resolution timing mechanism, `System.DateTime.Now` and `System.DateTime.UtcNow` are not necessarily going to be the best resource.  The Win32 API exposes "multimedia" timers and counters that are much more precise (say, 5-10 ms resolution vs. 50 ms).  [Here is an example of a class that uses win32 high resolution timers.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, time only moves forward, so you can trust that—assuming a stable environment—a `DateTime.Now`/`DateTime.UtcNow` will always be larger than one taken before that.

However, you should avoid to rely on this too much. There are things that may break this assumption. For local time, you need to be careful about DST, but even with universal time, there may be things that can affect you. You might be unlucky enough to hit the exact moment the time is synchronized with a server and corrects itself by going back two seconds. It’s unlikely but still a possibility.